# Fail Jenkins job getting a non-200 response from curl

Tags: curl, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that executes a curl command to POST to a url.  The curl command looks like this

```
curl -u user:pass -F file=@filetobeposted.zip -F install=true -v http://myserverurlhere.com:2222/service.jsp
```

The command returns XML with the results like...

```
    </log>
  </data>
  <status code="200">ok</status>
</response>
```

The Jenkins will be marked as failed if the curl command fails (as it should).  But the jenkins job will NOT be marked as failed if the curl command returns valid XML even though it may return a non-200 code.

How can I have Jenkins look at the results in the XML to determine pass/fail?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins marks failure on a step/job only when a non-zero exit code is received, and does not have any visibility/consideration for HTTP status codes.
Looks like you will need to create a custom step/script to parse the xml file, make the required check, and return 0 or 1 given the result.
Not sure whats your chosen language, but should be quite simple to accomplish even with basic bash - just exit 1 when condition for failure is met.